# Unable to see more than one component in Application Insights End-To-End transaction

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I have a simple MVC app that receives a POST request and submits it to an Azure Service Bus Topic.

```cs
public class DemoModel : PageModel
{
    public DemoModel(ServiceBusClient busClient)
    {
        _sender = busClient.CreateSender("actions");
    }

    public async Task OnPost()
    {
        var operationId = System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.RootId;
        var message = new ServiceBusMessage($"Event: {operationId}");
        await _sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Followed by a hosted service that consumes these messages:

```cs
public class Action1Handler : IHostedService
{
    // ...
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _processor = _busClient.CreateProcessor("actions", "all-reasonA");
        _processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
        return _processor.StartProcessingAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs arg)
    {
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = arg.Message;
        _logger.LogInformation("Body:, {body}", message.Body.ToString());

        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var client = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<WeatherClient>();

        using (_telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("sub operation"))
        {
            var lisbon = client.GetWeatherAsync("lisbon");
            var london = client.GetWeatherAsync("london");
            await Task.WhenAll(lisbon, london);

            _logger.LogInformation("Weather, {body}", lisbon.Result?.Region);
            _logger.LogInformation("Weather, {body}", london.Result?.Region);
        }

        var paris = await client.GetWeatherAsync("paris");
        _logger.LogInformation("Weather, {body}", paris?.Region);

        // complete the message. message is deleted from the queue. 
        await arg.CompleteMessageAsync(arg.Message);
    }
}
```

The issue starts with Application Insights, more specifically the End-To-End transaction view.
Basically I cannot see more than one component in the "timeline" view
[image: empty timeline]
Although all the traces, requests and logs are present with the correct operation Ids:
[image: app logs]

I assume the issue is somewhere in the id/parent_id relation, but I cannot figure it out what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what causes the issue but I've created a TelemetryFilter to filter some metrics and ended up with this graph, which is exactly what I wanted/expected.
[image]
The filter is as follows:

```cs
public class FilterServiceBus : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public FilterServiceBus(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // To filter out an item, return without calling the next processor.
        if (!OKtoSend(item)) { return; }

         this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    private bool OKtoSend(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if(item is DependencyTelemetry depedency)
        {
            return depedency.Name != "ServiceBusReceiver.Receive" && depedency.Name != "ServiceBusSender.Send" && depedency.Name != "ServiceBusReceiver.Complete";
        }

        return  true;
    }
}
```